# Subsequent citations of a Note in a translated Book. (Chicago Style)

Tags: citations, citation-style

I am using the Chicago-style Citation in a Paper that I am working on. I have written this in a paragraph:

> Es lässt sich vermuten, dass Platon etwas Bestimmtes in seinen Gedanken hatte, als er seine Ideen über Leiberziehung einbrachte. Man könnte sagen, dass die spartanische körperliche Erziehung für ihn ein Ausgangspunkt gewesen war, aus dem er seine Ideen zog.<sup>1</sup>

And here is the footnote:

> <sup>1</sup>   Vgl. Plato, *The Republic*, übers. Desmond Lee (London: Penguin Books Ltd., 2007), 67.

Vgl in German is equivalent to cf., compare, in English.

The text referenced is not by Plato himself, as you can see, but by the Translator, Desmond Lee. So the question I want to ask, ist that How do I write subsequent quotes, which are just Notes written by the translator Desmond Lee and not Plato himself?

I do apologize, in case the way I have written the footnote is wrong according to the Chicago-Style guidelines.